# Detect click on an element without class in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Why this doesn't work actually please?

```
<script>
$('button[type=submit]').not('.disabled').click(function(event) {
   alert('Button Clicked');
});
</script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Click me</button>
```

When I click on this button, it should fire the alert.

I also tried this:

```
$('button[type=submit]:not(.disabled)').click(function(event) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below works. The reason it doesn't work is probably because you don't have jQuery included. Add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to your code and it should work.

```js
$('button[type=submit]').not('.disabled').click(function(event) {
  alert('Button Clicked');
});
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Click me</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, it [wont work](https://jsfiddle.net/dpfb7Loz/) if the jQuery comes before the HTML, unless you [wait for the document to be ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/): [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/dpfb7Loz/1/). Or move the script below the HTML, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/dpfb7Loz/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use onclick() function instead of class.

```js
function btnClick(){
  alert('Button Clicked.');
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="btnClick();" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Click me</button>
```